How to determine exact output impedance of the source degeneration using feedback analysis?
How can I get the EXACT output impedance when looking from the drain side of the source degeneration using FEEDBACK ANALYSIS?

It can be derived easily using a couple of methods, but I'm having some problems obtaining the EXACT result using the feedback approach.
To me, this is a current-voltage (series-series) feedback type. Therefore, the output impedance with feedback would increase by a factor of \$1 + LG\$ compared to no feedback, where LG is the loop gain.
It also seems to me that no feedback would mean that the voltage across \$R_s\$ is zero \$V_{R_s} = 0\$, so \$R_{\text{out, no fb}} = r_o\$. However, I'm stuck on how to calculate the exact loop gain in this case.
I want the EXACT result. 
Can anyone help me figure out how to calculate it?

Here you will find what you wanted https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295771/i-o-resistance-of-common-source-mosfet-with-source-degeneration/295966#295966

@G36 Hi, I can do small signal analysis to get the result, but I would like to use feedback for this. I also want to get the exact result as shown.

I see, but my solution shows the exact result.

@G36 but I want to apply feedback theory for this for pracitce.

In that case, take a look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/122968/output-impedance-of-current-series-feedback-bjt-amplifier/122975#122975

@G36 Actually, I also obtained that result when I checked the example on page 15 of the document below. The approximated loop gain is gm * Rs, so the output impedance is ro * (1 + gm * Rs). This is still an approximation because the loop gain calculation does not take ro into account.
https://in.ncu.edu.tw/~ncume_ee/harvard-es154/lect_18_feedback.pdf

If I take ro into account, then the loop gain seems to depend on what is connected to the drain side, which makes it more complicated and a bit confusing.

But the main purpose of feedback analysis is to get a quick approximation solution. If we want to have a full expression we need to use a circuit analysis instead.

Yeah, you're right. I think I made things more complicated, but I'm curious about how to get the exact result using feedback.
